# Setting per-file flags with automake

Tags: linux, gcc, automake

Is there a way set flags on a per-file basis with automake?
In particular, if I have a c++ project and want to compile with -WAll all the files except one for which I want to disable a particular warning, what could I do?

I tried something like:

```
CXXFLAGS = -WAll ...
bin_PROGRAMS = test
test_SOURCES = main.cpp utility.cpp
utility_o_CXXFLAGS = $(CXXFLAGS) -Wno-unused-value
```

but it didn't work.

EDITED: removed reference to automake manual, which was actually misleading (thanks to Douglas Leeder).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Automake only supports per-target flags, while you want per-object flags.  One way around is to create a small library that contains your object:

```
CXXFLAGS = -Wall ...
bin_PROGRAMS = test
test_SOURCES = main.cpp
test_LDADD = libutility.a
noinst_LIBRARIES = libutility.a
libutility_a_SOURCES = utility.cpp
libutility_a_CXXFLAGS = $(CXXFLAGS) -Wno-unused-value
```

Answer (score 17):

You can't do this with `automake`... but *can do* with `make` =) Add following line to your `Makefile.am`:

```
utility.$(OBJEXT) : CXXFLAGS += -Wno-unused-value
```

See [GNU Make documentation : Target-specific Variable Values](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html#Target_002dspecific) for details.

Comment: The question now is rather old, but the answer is interesting nevertheless, thanks :)

Comment: i believe, there is a mistype in `Makefile.am` above. probably it should say `Makefile`. adding the line suggested above to `Makefile.am` won't work.

the create-a-small-library solution below has worked like a charm for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/201418/5634966

Answer (score 2):

You've got confused - that section is referring to options to automake itself.

It's a way of setting the automake command-line options:

> -W CATEGORY
>   --warnings=category
>       Output warnings falling in category. category can be one of:
>
> ```
> gnu
>     warnings related to the GNU Coding Standards (see Top).
> obsolete
>     obsolete features or constructions
> override
>     user redefinitions of Automake rules or variables
> portability
>     portability issues (e.g., use of make features that are known to be not portable)
> syntax
>     weird syntax, unused variables, typos
> unsupported
>     unsupported or incomplete features
> all
>     all the warnings
> none
>     turn off all the warnings
> error
>     treat warnings as errors
> ```
>
> A category can be turned off by prefixing its name with ‘no-’.
>   For instance, -Wno-syntax will hide the
>   warnings about unused variables.
>
> The categories output by default are ‘syntax’ and ‘unsupported’.
>   Additionally, ‘gnu’ and ‘portability’
>   are enabled in --gnu and --gnits
>   strictness.
>
> The environment variable WARNINGS can contain a comma separated list of
>   categories to enable. It will be taken
>   into account before the command-line
>   switches, this way -Wnone will also
>   ignore any warning category enabled by
>   WARNINGS. This variable is also used
>   by other tools like autoconf; unknown
>   categories are ignored for this
>   reason.

The per-file listed in section 17 refers to per-Makefile not source file.

I'm not aware of any per-source file flag setting, but you can set the option for each result binary with:

```
binaryname_CXXFLAGS
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable a particular warning in a specific compilation unit, you can use `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored -W...`, as described in the [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html).