# Mixing C++98 and C++11 source in automake/gcc

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, autoconf, automake

I have a list of cpp files in project which is built using automake tools.

Some of them are written using pre-C++11 standard (ie C++98) and they cannot compile with c++11 flag of gcc (-std=c++11).

Latest cpp files are using C++11 standard and they need -std=c++11 flag in compile.

Can I define in Automake two lists of cpp source files and give different compilation flags?

Comment: Whatever the answer, consider upgrading the old sources. In the long run, that will make your life easier.

Comment: If you mix C98 and C11 in the same executable you may get problems. If you are using boost you are very likely to get problems.

Comment: @Deduplicator and n.m. Thank you for the advice. Since it is difficult to convert full project at once, I will use this solution as temporary solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is ripped directly from [Setting per-file flags with automake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149324/setting-per-file-flags-with-automake)

You may bundle your c++11 code into a lib and provide different flags for this code subset in Makefile.am

```
bin_PROGRAMS        = test 
test_SOURCES        = main.cpp 
test_LDADD          = c11code.la 
noinst_LTLIBRARIES  = c11code.la  
c11code_la_SOURCES  = cxx1_1.cpp cxx1_2.cpp cxx1_3.cpp 
c11code_la_CXXFLAGS = $(CXXFLAGS) -std=c++11
```