# Compile C file within C++ library in Makefile.am

Tags: makefile, autotools, automake

I am forking an existing project on Github that I want to make some changes to. One thing I want to do is add an extra file. This file should be in one of the libraries that the Makefile.am generates. The problem is that the file I want to add is a .c file, while everything else in the project is .cpp.

The library that should contain the file is used like this in the makefile:

```
MYLIBRARY=path/mylibrary.a

...

path_mylibrary_a_CPPFLAGS = $(AM_CPPFLAGS)
path_mylibrary_a_CXXFLAGS = $(AM_CXXFLAGS)
path_mylibrary_a_SOURCES = \
  path/cppfile1.cpp \
  path/cppfile1.h \
  path/cppfile2.cpp \
  path/cppfile2.h \
  path/cppfile3.cpp \
  path/cppfile3.h

...

mybinary_LDADD = $(MYLIBRARY)
```

Simply adding the `path/cfile.c` and `path/cfile.h` to the list of sources gives me the following error:

```
CXXLD    mybinary
/usr/bin/ld: path/mylibrary.a(path_mylibrary_a-cfile.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
path/mylibrary.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
```

What can I do so the Makefile.am will compile the c file in a project that otherwise is built in c++?

Comment: Maybe you should add a `path_mylibrary_a_CFLAGS` variable? Suitably initialized of course.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way to solve this problem is to have a convenience library in which you compile your c code:

```
path_mylibrary_a_LDADD = cfile.la

noinst_LTLIBRARIES = cfile.la
cfile_la_CPPFLAGS = -std=c11
cfile_la_SOURCES = cfile.c
```

For more information refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26906219/mixing-c98-and-c11-source-in-automake-gcc).

Comment: I've tried this with many variations, but it creates a different problem. In a .cpp file where I'm referencing the .c file, I get an error saying the reference is undefined, which is the same as if I don't include the .c file at all in the makefile.

Comment: Reference undefined is a linker problem. You might want to check using objdump if the symbols are defined.

Comment: Also including a .c file in a .cpp file would not work unless you use extern "C" block

Comment: Try just including the header file in the cpp file

Comment: I am only including the header file.

Comment: This still uses the C compiler, not the C++ compiler, for the source file.

Answer (score 0):

I presume your `cfile.h` has the structure

```
#ifndef MYLIBRARY_CFILE_H
#define MYLIBRARY_CFILE_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/* your C declarations here */

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* MYLIBRARY_CFILE_H */
```

Also, as a general tip: If you want to add a few source files to a library or program in a `Makefile.am` file, just add the lines

```
path_mylibrary_a_SOURCES += cfile.c cfile.h
```

which makes for a very clean patch which only adds one line, does not touch other lines, etc.

Also, I concur with https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude on the `path_mylibrary_a_CFLAGS` which you probably need to add as well.

Comment: This still uses the C compiler, not the C++ compiler, for the source file.

Comment: C and C++ are distinct languages. Using the C compiler for a source file written in C is the proper thing to do. The C++ compiler and linker will then use the C linkage to link to the object file the C compiler created and the C++ program can access the objects from the C sources.

Comment: *"Using the C compiler for a source file written in C is the proper thing to do"* - According to whom? The compiler folks tell us to use the same compiler and flags to compile source files in a project. For C++ projects that means use the C++ compiler for C source files. It ensures C source files git the options they need, like `-frtti` and `-fexceptions`.

Comment: Where are *"the compiler folks telling us"* to use C++ compilers for compiling C code? (Using `g++` to *link* object files generated from both C++ and C with `g++` and `gcc` respectively is different from *compiling*.)