# How can I enable option '-Werror' using a GCC pragma?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I have a few files where I'd like to be strict about warnings, and I use GCC to build my project.

I've tried `#pragma GCC diagnostic error "-Wall"` as per *[6.57.10 Diagnostic Pragmas](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html)*, but it fails to account for some other enabled warning types:

```
foo.c:666:6: warning: passing argument 2 of 'bar' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
```

Is there a way to enable [-Werror](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Werror) for the file like it was supplied from the command line (or, at least, for the implicitly enabled set of warnings), so any warning would trigger an error?

Comment: I've only tried this on clang, which attempts to be compatible with gcc, but `#pragma GCC diagnostic error "-Wall"` (without the [] brackets) seems to work just fine.  The docs in your link don't have brackets in any of the examples, so I'm not sure why you have them.  Typo?

Answer (score 1):

For this case, you can use

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic error "-Wincompatible-pointer-types"
```

as for example in

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic error "-Wincompatible-pointer-types"
void foo(int * a)
{
}

void bar() {
        foo("foo");
}
```

Using [-Wall](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wall) with this pragma is not supported. Only diagnostic options are supported, that are shown with `-fdiagnostics-show-option` (which is the default today anyway), as in your example warning above.

Comment: At least with GCC 7.2.0 and later, `#pragma GCC diagnostics error "-Wall"` and `#pragma GCC diagnostics error "-Wextra"` seem to convert numerous warnings into errors.  However, there do seem to be some blind spots — I also found `-Wpointer-compare` was not converted to an error.  Such omissions can be rectified by `#pragma GCC diagnostics error "-Wpointer-compare"`.  If I needed to do this on a regular basis, I'd create a header to define the pragmata for the errors that I want generated.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, it turns out the current semantics of the [-Wall](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wall) option are described on [the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc). In my case of GCC 8.3.0, it says that it enables the following options that could be used with the pragma afterwards:

> -Waddress -Warray-bounds=1 (only with -O2) -Wbool-compare -Wbool-operation -Wc++11-compat  -Wc++14-compat -Wcatch-value (C++ and Objective-C++ only) -Wchar-subscripts -Wcomment -Wduplicate-decl-specifier (C and Objective-C
> only) -Wenum-compare (in C/ObjC; this is on by default in C++) -Wformat -Wint-in-bool-context -Wimplicit (C and Objective-C only) -Wimplicit-int (C and Objective-C only) -Wimplicit-function-declaration (C and Objective-C
> only) -Winit-self (only for C++) -Wlogical-not-parentheses -Wmain (only for C/ObjC and unless -ffreestanding) -Wmaybe-uninitialized -Wmemset-elt-size -Wmemset-transposed-args -Wmisleading-indentation (only for C/C++)
> -Wmissing-attributes -Wmissing-braces (only for C/ObjC) -Wmultistatement-macros -Wnarrowing (only for C++) -Wnonnull -Wnonnull-compare -Wopenmp-simd -Wparentheses -Wpointer-sign -Wreorder -Wrestrict -Wreturn-type
> -Wsequence-point -Wsign-compare (only in C++) -Wsizeof-pointer-div -Wsizeof-pointer-memaccess -Wstrict-aliasing -Wstrict-overflow=1 -Wstringop-truncation -Wswitch -Wtautological-compare -Wtrigraphs -Wuninitialized
> -Wunknown-pragmas -Wunused-function -Wunused-label -Wunused-value -Wunused-variable -Wvolatile-register-var

It's likely that the list may change with time. On the other hand, `diagnostic error`ing over a version-dependent list may be a bad idea as it may break compilation for users that are likely to use some other versions of the toolchain than developers do (that [-Werror](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Werror) is infamous for), so explicitly listing the desired warnings is good for public relations.